# Landscape-Portrait orientation in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, orientation

I am new to WPF and working on dynamic view creation. I have a scenario where i need to modify my UI based on monitor landscape and/or portrait, like [image]

I already have property which tells me that monitor is in landscape or portrait mode.

Is this possible in WPF?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is possible. You would create a view that implements both layouts and switches between them using a DataTrigger:

```
<ContentControl>
    <ContentControl.Style>
        <Style TargetType="ContentControl">
            <Setter Property="Content">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <!-- Put your portrait layout here -->
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsLandscape}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Content">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <!-- Put your landscape layout here -->
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ContentControl.Style>        
</ContentControl>
```

Using the {Binding IsLandscape} expression, the DataTrigger observes the IsLandscape property of the view's DataContext. [This is explained in detail on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347(v=vs.110).aspx). This means that you should set the view's DataContext property to the object that has the IsLandscape property that you've mentioned in your question. Full example:

1. Create new empty WPF project.
2. Update your `MainWindow.xaml.cs`:

   ```
   public MainWindow()
   {
       this.InitializeComponent();

       this.DataContext = this; // You would put a ViewModel here when using MVVM design pattern
   }

   public static readonly DependencyProperty IsLandscapeProperty
       = DependencyProperty.Register("IsLandscape",
                                       typeof (bool),
                                       typeof (MainWindow));

   public bool IsLandscape
   {
       get { return (bool) GetValue(IsLandscapeProperty); }
       set { SetValue(IsLandscapeProperty, value); }
   }

   private void ChangeOrientation(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
       this.IsLandscape = !this.IsLandscape;
   }
   ```
3. Update your `MainWindow.xaml`. Delete the default Grid and put this instead:

   ```
   <Window.Resources>
       <Style TargetType="UserControl">
           <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
           <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
           <Setter Property="Background" Value="#CCDDEE" />
           <Setter Property="Margin" Value="3" />
       </Style>
   </Window.Resources>

   <DockPanel>

       <Button DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Margin="5" Content="Change Orientation"
               Click="ChangeOrientation" />

       <ContentControl>
           <ContentControl.Style>
               <Style TargetType="ContentControl">
                   <Setter Property="Content">
                       <Setter.Value>
                           <Grid>
                               <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                   <ColumnDefinition />
                                   <ColumnDefinition />
                               </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                               <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                   <RowDefinition />
                                   <RowDefinition />
                               </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                               <UserControl Content="Sub 1" />
                               <UserControl Grid.Column="1" Content="Sub 2" />
                               <UserControl Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Content="Main" />
                           </Grid>
                       </Setter.Value>
                   </Setter>
                   <Style.Triggers>
                       <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsLandscape}" Value="True">
                           <Setter Property="Content">
                               <Setter.Value>
                                   <Grid>
                                       <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                           <ColumnDefinition />
                                           <ColumnDefinition />
                                       </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                       <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                           <RowDefinition />
                                           <RowDefinition />
                                       </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                                       <UserControl Grid.Column="1" Content="Sub 1" />
                                       <UserControl Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Content="Sub 2" />
                                       <UserControl Grid.RowSpan="2" Content="Main" />
                                   </Grid>
                               </Setter.Value>
                           </Setter>
                       </DataTrigger>
                   </Style.Triggers>
               </Style>
           </ContentControl.Style>
       </ContentControl>

   </DockPanel>
   ```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. As i said i am new to WPF,an you please brief me on Binding="{Binding IsLandscape}"

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can implement both of this UI and use [VisualStateManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.visualstatemanager(v=vs.110).aspx) to control which UI to display.

Also you can bind visibility of layout container to your property using [converter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)