# Orientation-based layout for WPF grid rows

Tags: c#, wpf

If I have a `Grid` in WPF and I would like to have the `RowDefinitions` base their height off of what orientation the device currently is in, how would I accomplish this?

For example, when my app is in landscape mode my default `RowDefinitions` are:

```
   <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height=".25*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height=".50*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height=".1*"/>
   </Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

However, this looks silly when in portrait mode. In portrait mode I would rather have the `RowDefinitions` be something like:

```
   <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height=".15*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height=".75*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height=".1*"/>
   </Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

I could probably just bind each `Height` to a property in my ViewModel that reflects the current orientation and then use a converter to set the height, but that doesn't seem like the correct way to approach this.

Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: http://blogs.claritycon.com/blog/2008/11/building-a-column-major-uniformgrid-in-wpf/ have a look at this link

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at this question.

[Landscape-Portrait orientation in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27712110/landscape-portrait-orientation-in-wpf)

you will need to create a view which implements both landscape and horizontal and change the View using a property and a DataTrigger which you need to bind the input from the device setting the orientation at the moment.

you can also switch the using DataTrigger or DataTemplate it depends on how big and complex your UI is.